# Is there a way to increase time efficiency instead of print()?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, time-complexity

There's this python3 code that makes a very large number and outputs it

```
Big_number = 1
i=1
while(i != 100000):
    Big_number = Big_number*i
    i +=1
print(Big_number)
```

It takes a very long time to print out 'Big_number'. Use sys.stdin.readline instead of input() to reduce time. Is there another output method that can reduce execution time?

Comment: Are you taking into consideration that you are iterating 100000 times in a loop before printing that number? Is the loop taking the time or the print itself? Also I am not sure why readline() would be faster than input() in python3. I mean yes, input() does more things but there shouldn't be a huge difference. Atleast that's what I just researched.

Comment: the print statement itself takes 3 seconds on my machine